# jquery error:microsoft jscript runtime error '$' is undefined jquery?

Tags: asp.net

i used the following jquery for validation of particular div.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnNext').click(function () {
            if ($('#page1 input[id$=txt_companyname]').val() == "") {
                alert('company Name is Blank!');
                $('#page1 input[id$=txt_companyname]').focus();
            }
            else if ($('#page1 input[id$=txt_headoff]').val() == "") {
                alert('Password is Blank!');
                $('#page1 input[id$=txt_headoff]').focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

i have the button in this page, if i click the btn without filling these field, then the alert msg should displayed.

```
<div id="page1" runat="server" style=" padding-left:10px">
<div class="divsize">
                    <div class="labelsize"><asp:Label ID="lbl_companyname" runat="server" Text="1. Name of the Company" ></asp:Label></div>
                    <div class="labelcolon"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=":" ></asp:Label></div>
                    <div class="labelsize"><asp:TextBox ID="txt_companyname" runat="server" Width="250px" ></asp:TextBox></div>
                </div>
                <div class="divsize">
                    <div class="labelsize"><asp:Label ID="lbl_headoff" runat="server" Text="2. a) Head Office / Registered Office" ></asp:Label></div>
                    <div class="labelcolon"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=":"></asp:Label></div>
                    <div class="labelsize"><asp:TextBox ID="txt_headoff" runat="server" 
                        TextMode="MultiLine" Width="250px" ></asp:TextBox></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for this error:

1. You have not referenced the jQuery library.
2. You are calling the function before the library is loaded.
3. Using another library which has redefined what "$" is.

If you have referenced jQuery properly and there is no other library redefining "$", then you should call your function when document is ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    //All your code here.
    });
```

Comment: hi Ashwin Singh, i used but, it doesnt do any action.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#btnNext').Click(function()
        {
        if ($('#page1 input[id$=txt_companyname]').val() == "")
        {
        alert('company Name is Blank!');
        $('#page1 input[id$=txt_companyname]').focus();
        }
        else if ($('#page1 input[id$=txt_headoff]').val() == "")
        {
        alert('Password is Blank!');
        $('#page1 input[id$=txt_headoff]').focus();
        }
        }
    });
    </script>

Comment: Where did you add your reference to jquery library? Show me that part.

Comment: i didnt add any thing. am new to jquery, so plz tell me what should add.

Comment: You should add the following under head <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: i added this line, then also no action ashwin

Comment: Can you post your full html in the question?

Comment: i cant post the entire html, space is not enough here... my need is i have 3 div, and btn like next, previous...same like wizard control in asp.net... if i click the next btn in div1 without filling the field means, it should show the alert msg. so i tried the above code

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Click'

Comment: i changed it, but now no action, it just navigate to next div, when i click the btn, i added the query above in this page